# Recovering a deleted good answer on my own question

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers, vote-to-undelete

I asked [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23998443/what-isnt-typeable-in-ghc-7-8) earlier which got an answer from a well-respected (I'll speak for myself) contributor to the Haskell tag. The answer contributed to my understanding of the problem and generated quite a bit of insightful discussion in the comments I saw. Unfortunately, the answer was deleted. I see this as a case of [deleted-but-good-answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/365/why-should-10k-rep-users-view-self-deleted-answers). It's not something I was ready to accept, but it was contributing to the conversation. I also don't know what I missed since the last time I viewed the answer/comments.

What is the appropriate channel for trying to get this answer and associated discussion back to my question?

Comment: The poster deleted the answer himself, leaving the comment: *"I think I'm just going to delete this answer. I posed it suggestively, but really it's more speculative than substantial."*

Comment: That's a shame, is there any way for it to come back?

Comment: Why would I override the poster's wishes?

Comment: It's his opinion that his answer wasn't worthy. It's my opinion that it was contributing to the discussion and to my understanding of the issue. I feel like a question that contributes should be kept around. I'm not necessarily suggesting that you override, though that's one method. Perhaps I'm misunderstanding the [vote-to-undelete] tag on MSO, but I thought there might be a way for the community to decide.

Comment: It would have to be an Academy Award answer to override the poster's wishes.  I don't think there's that much value here.  Certainly, three community users can vote to undelete.

Comment: Presumably that requires some minimum reputation that I have not yet acquired... Is it 10k so that I can see the deleted answer and then also vote to undelete it?

Comment: Yes, [you need 10K to see it and 20K to help undelete it](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/).  It looks like it has 2 undelete votes already.

Answer (score -2):

I added the third undelete vote to https://stackoverflow.com/a/23999108/14768 today and it's now visible again.

I can't say the answer is good, but if OP of the question says the answer should be undeleted and it doesn't look like spam, I'm willing to give him the benefit of the doubt.

Comment: *... five years later*